# Пунктуация в «Балладе о даурском бароне»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, прямая-речь, вставка

*«Случилось несчастье! —

Он выдавил, —

(Дабы

Удар отклонить —

Сокрушительный вздох), —

С испугу ли, —

Все-таки крикнула баба, —

Иль гнили объевшись, но…

Ворон издох!»*
Арсений Несмелов. Баллада о даурском бароне
(Печатный вариант: Серебряный век. Лирика. — Минск, Харвест, 2000)

Есть [такой](https://lot1959.livejournal.com/8574.html) вариант пунктуации:
*«Случилось несчастье! —

Он выдавил

(Дабы

Удар отклонить —

Сокрушительный вздох). —

С испугу ли —

Все-таки крикнула баба —

Иль гнили объевшись, но...

Ворон издох!»*

И [такой](https://hatushin.ru/biblioteka/74-zabytyj-poet-belogo-dvizheniya.html):
*«Случилось несчастье! —

Он выдавил

(Дабы

Удар отклонить —

Сокрушительный вздох). —

С испугу ли

Все-таки крикнула баба,

Иль гнили объевшись,

Но...

Ворон издох!»*

И предостаточно "всяких-разных" других вариантов.
Честное слово, я запуталась и не смогла решить — какая из пунктуационных версий правильна? А как Вы видите оформление этого отрывка?

Answer (score 1):

Видеть следует, как то автором задумано, а он позапрошловековой. Иные были орфография с пунктуацией. "Мутной тоскою оборон..." (Что сделан?! Это где? Это лифт?) "Шептались пески, умирал небосклон", - о, дайте, дайте мне атмосфэры!

В Инете нет одного варианта баллады с "правильной" современной пунктуацией - то одна ошибка, то другая, как в процитированных Вами трёх вариантах. Даже слово во второй стоке двоится (рыжели - ржавели). Но, поперебиравши, можно наскрести-набрести на авторскую задумку - вычислив-скомпилировав ея.

Да, ещё поэт хочет сочетанья зап-тире при вставках ("с испугу ли, – все-таки крикнула баба, – иль гнили объевшись"; "кавказский клинок, - он уже обнажен, - в гниющее...") , причём новая строка - с тире, чего издательство разрешить никак не может, а оригинал, - где он, этот оригинал? Ещё, сдаётся, не дробит на строфы и не кавычит прямую речь, но -

такую текстологическую работу предполагает академическое издание.

Вот так разрешОно (к примеру):

---

---

К оврагу,

где травы рыжели <ржавели> от крови,

где смерть опрокинула трупы на склон,

папаху надвинув на самые брови,

на чёрном коне подъезжает барон.

---

Он спустится шагом к изрубленным трупам,

и смотрит им в лица,

склоняясь с седла, –

и прядает конь,

оседающий крупом,

и в пене испуга его удила.

---

И яростью,

бредом её истомяся,

кавказский клинок —

он уже обнажён –

в гниющее

красноармейское мясо,

повиснув к земле,

погружает барон.

---

Скакун обезумел,

не слушает шпор он,

выносит на гребень,

весь в лунном огне, –

испуганный шумом,

проснувшийся ворон

закаркает хрипло на чёрной сосне.

---

И каркает ворон,

и слушает всадник,

и льдисто светлеет худое лицо.

Чем возгласы птицы звучат безотрадней,

тем

сжавшее сердце

слабеет кольцо.

---

Глаза засветились.

В тревожном их блеске –

две крошечных искры,

два тонких луча...

Но нынче,

вернувшись из страшной поездки,

барон приказал:

«Позовите врача!»

---

И лекарю,

мутной тоскою оборон

(шаги и бряцание шпор в тишине),

отрывисто бросил:

«Хворает мой ворон:

увидев меня,

не закаркал он мне!

---

Ты будешь лечить его,

если ж последней

отрады лишусь — посчитаюсь с тобой!..»

Врач вышел безмолвно,

и тут же, в передней,

руками развёл и покончил с собой.

---

А в полдень,

в кровавом Особом Отделе,

барону,

в сторонку дохнув перегар,

сказали:

«Вот эти... Они засиделись:

Она — партизанка, а он — комиссар».

---

И медленно,

в шёпот тревожных известий –

они напряжёнными стали опять –

им брошено:

«На ночь сведите их вместе,

а ночью — под вороном — расстрелять!»

---

И утром начштаба барону прохаркал

о ночи и смерти казнённых двоих...

«А ворон их видел?

А ворон закаркал?» —

барон перебил...

И полковник затих.

---

«Случилось несчастье! –

он выдавил

(дабы

удар отклонить –

сокрушительный вздох). –

С испугу ли –

всё–таки крикнула баба –

иль гнили объевшись, но...

ворон издох!»

---

«Каналья!

Ты сдохнешь, а ворон мой — умер!

Он,

каркая,

славил удел палача!.. —

От гнева и ужаса обезумев,

хватаясь за шашку,

барон закричал.  —

---

Он был моим другом.

В кровавой неволе

другого найти я уже не смогу!»

И, весь содрогаясь от гнева и боли,

он отдал приказ отступать на Ургу.

---

Стенали степные поджарые волки,

шептались пески,

умирал небосклон...

Как идол, сидел на косматой монголке,

монголом одет,

сумасшедший барон.

---

И, шорохам ночи бессонной внимая,

он призраку гибели выплюнул:

«Прочь!»

И каркала вороном

глухонемая,

упавшая сзади,

даурская ночь.

---

---

Я слышал:

В монгольских унылых улусах,

ребёнка качая при дымном огне,

раскосая женщина в кольцах и бусах

поёт о бароне на чёрном коне...

---

И будто бы в дни,

когда в яростной злобе

шевелится буря в горячем песке, –

огромный,

он мчит над пустынею Гоби,

и ворон сидит у него на плече.

---

**[Источник-1](http://litresp.ru/chitat/ru/%D0%9D/nesmelov-arsenij/sobranie-sochinenij-v-2-h-tomah-ti--stihotvoreniya-i-poemi)**

**[Источник-2](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8rNrCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD.&source=bl&ots=P9VfYcm4Pg&sig=XC3BISnsbpQXEIHk18bR5dlkAW0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYl_CM0crcAhUGLFAKHYBGCY8Q6AEwCnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)**

**[Источник-3](https://www.promegalit.ru/public/16261__arsenij_nesmelov_1889-1945.html)**

---

Да, ещё нашлось в [Викитеке](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5_(%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)) - это достаточно авторитетно. Я туда не подглядывала!